# Cannot read property 'push' of undefined. Angular 2

Tags: angular, typescript

I have this inside a method in Angular 2.

```
exportClass AppComponent implements OnInit{

private averageList: number [] = number [];

(...)

    getAverage(){

    this.averageList = [];
    (....)
    (....)

        var source = Observable.forkJoin(
          this.http.get(data2.builds[0].url + this.finalURL),
          this.http.get(data2.builds[1].url + this.finalURL)
        );

        var subscription = source.subscribe(
          function (x) {
            let numberOfFails = 0;
            let count = 0;
            for(var i = 0; i < x.length; i++ ){
              let data = x[i].json();
              contador++;
              if (data.result === "FAILURE"){
                numberOfFails++;
              }
            }
            let average = numberOfFails/count;
            console.log(numberOfFails + " " + count);
            console.log(average);
            this.averageList.push(average);  //THIS LINE MAKES AN ERROR
          },
          function (err) {
            console.log('Error: %s', err);
          },
          function () {
            console.log('Completed');
          });
    }
}
```

When I try to add an element into the array averageList the next issue appears: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined.
At the begining of the method I clean this array using this.averageList = [].
how can I fix this to use the array? Thanks

Comment: How is averageList defined? In the code provided I don't see it defined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your callback to `source.subscribe` is not an arrow function so it's `this` value is not that of the class, to get the desired result change the `source.subscribe` to use an arrow function. find below the arrow function equivalent.

```
 var subscription = source.subscribe(
      (x) => {
        let numberOfFails = 0;
        let count = 0;
        for(var i = 0; i < x.length; i++ ){
          let data = x[i].json();
          contador++;
          if (data.result === "FAILURE"){
            numberOfFails++;
          }
        }
        let average = numberOfFails/count;
        console.log(numberOfFails + " " + count);
        console.log(average);
        this.averageList.push(average);  //THIS LINE MAKES AN ERROR
      },
     (err) => {
        console.log('Error: %s', err);
      },
     () => {
        console.log('Completed');
      });
```

Comment: How can I do that? I am new in this

Comment: @CarlosY I have updated my answer with the arrow function equivalent